# Changing of data between Spinners

Tags: android

i have three spinners in my android application.

```
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:entries="@array/country_arrays"                            
            android:hint="SELECT"
            />
```

like this spinner 1 and 2.
and here is my java code:

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){    
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);

            startActivity(in);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                    "OnClickListener : " + 
                    "\n No.of.Adults : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                    "\n No.of.Children : " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()) +
                    "\n No.of.Infants : " + 
        }
    });
}
```

like this

Here I passed the value for the spinners through xml like this :

```
<.string-array name="number_arrays">
    <.item>0</item>
    <.item>1</item>
    <.item>2</item>
    <.item>3</item>
    <.item>4</item>
    <.item>5</item>
    <.item>6</item>
    <.item>7</item>
    <.item>8</item>
    <.item>9</item>
<./string-array>
```

Here I simply used dots for displaying the code.

Now the thing is that... if the value in spinner1 is 1 the second spinner has to show only 8 counts.. the total for the two spinners must be strictly 9.
If spinner1=2 then spinner must show from 1 to 7 counts. likewise...
Please someone help me to solve this thing without any database.. by simply using for loops.